# Libreoffice impress: animate (change color ) a single word, not full sentence?

Tags: libreoffice, presentations, libreoffice-impress

I would like to have animations in a LibreOffice Impress presentation, where a single word in `item A` changes once I move to `item B`. If I want to do it for the full `item A`, it's rather easy: select the text field, go to Animation->Add->Category:Emphasis ->Effect: Change Font Color'.

But I want the effect to apply to a single word not the full sentence. Is this possible (without a hack lack duplicating the text field)?